# Is there a way to disable BBCode parsing in Channel Entries?

Tags: parsing

I have several articles that contain "[I]" as part of a quote. EE sees this as BBcode and renders the entire remainder of the entry as italic text (because there is no corresponding closing tag).

The only other mention of this issue I can find is in an [archived EL forum thread from several years ago](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/183587/), which suggests there is no way to change this default behavior... Is there still no way to disable BBCode parsing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use an html entity to overcome this. Try changing your [I] (capital i?) to:

```
[&#73;]
```

in your EE entries and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the same [answer I gave in the other thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24143/wygwam-making-i-italicise-content/25338#25338) (is it ok to do that on SE?):

> Heh... I used to run into this all the time on forums. The slightly
>   hacky but fairly straightforward workaround is to "interrupt" the
>   BBCode you *don't* want to get parsed with something that *does* get
>   parsed into an invisible output, such as an empty tag.
>
> So when you have this:
>
> ```
> He said "[i]t was a fine day for sailing..."
> ```
>
> Do this:
>
> ```
> He said "[[b][/b]i]t was a fine day for sailing..."
> ```
>
> More details in [my comment to the EE docs' BBCode tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/bbcode.html#13397).