# WYGWAM making [i] italicise content

Tags: wygwam, tags, formatting

I've a client who has written an article with footnotes.

Those footnotes are notated by them adding [i] [ii] and so on.

For some reason though, WYGWAM seems to take that as a cue to open italics.

Won't be surprised to find this is one of CKEditor's advanced config settings but not sure what should be changed.

Has anyone experienced similar?

Answer (score 3):

It's a BBCode problem: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/bbcode.html

Pretty sure the issue here is the first [i] only, all subsequent [ii], [iii] should not be replaced as bbcode by EE.

A dirty but effective method would be to change the very first instance of [i] to [&#105;] which is the html entity for the letter i.

I tried a more elegant method using Low Replace but I think the parse order was doing its thing as usual.

Hope it gets you somewhere.
jfp

Comment: +1 This is a long standing issue, you can't currently disable BB decode with a setting ([forum thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/183587/)). Next to encoding the bracket or i-character, you can probably use some other work-around tactics, like make the "i" italic yourself, e.g. becomes ``[<em>i</em>]`` so EE won't recognize it as BB code. Or, get creative with the CK style dropdown and CSS:before:content for footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

Heh... I used to run into this all the time on forums. The slightly hacky but fairly straightforward workaround is to "interrupt" the BBCode you *don't* want to get parsed with something that *does* get parsed into an invisible output, such as an empty tag.

So when you have this:

```
He said "[i]t was a fine day for sailing..."
```

Do this:

```
He said "[[b][/b]i]t was a fine day for sailing..."
```

More details in [my comment to the EE docs' BBCode tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/bbcode.html#13397).

Answer (score 0):

A common problem it seems https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19755/i-in-entry-text-interpreted-as-unclosed-bbcode-italics

I tried the extension that Derek posted but it has stopped all fields from rendering.